# How to select a specific value from a table

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an code for each file I have. My problem is that I cannot use:

```
for(int i =0 .... i++)
```

I do not want to check every line in the table, I want to check a specific file, and I need the code for that specific file.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    static struct CHECKFILE
    {
        const char *s_File;
        const char *s_SpecialCode;
    } s_check_code[] = {
           "file_1" , "code_1"
           "file_2" , "code_2"
           "file_3" , "code_3"
           "file_4" , "code_4"
           "file_5" , "code_5"
       };


   std::string str;
   str.append(s_check_code[file_1].s_SpecialCode);

   std::cout << str << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you need is to study C++'s basics, before moving on...

Comment: Maybe, but i know if i do something like this http://prntscr.com/lk4b6x will work but i wander if is posibile to do it without checking every line.

Comment: Ofcourse you can do that. With `"file_1"` instead of `file_1` and you need the right associative container. You can checkout std::map or std::unordered_map . Which one is right might depend on you application.

Comment: Yep, i didn't know about <map>. Thank you.

Comment: Or use s_check_code[0]. C++ arrays are zero indexed. If you want mapping from string to content use std::(unordered_)map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of `std::string` to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{

   std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap = {
       {"file_1" , "code_1"},
       {"file_2" , "code_2"},
       {"file_3" , "code_3"},
       {"file_4" , "code_4"},
       {"file_5" , "code_5"}
   };

   std::string str;
   str.append(myMap["file_1"]);

   std::cout << str << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

See it live [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78893e781cab4ea3).